# Add Expandable list in fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I made a two tabs with fragment.
I want to add on the first tab an expandable list, but I don't know how since every example I find shows how to implement it on an activity.
I want to make it like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qbsS.png]

Comment: It's the same as putting any other View in a Fragment... Just that an ExpandableListView is somewhat a bit more complicate, but it's perfectly doable.

Comment: You would add it exactly the same way as you would in an activity. You put it in your layout.xml file, inflate that file in your fragment onCreateView() method and then populate the data accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FrameLayout xmlns ....
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="math_parent" >

        <ExpandableListView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/list"
              ...   />


</FrameLayout>
```

create new Fragment Class

```
public ExpendListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ExpendableListView mList;

    public void onCreateView(...... ) {

         View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_layout,container,false);
         mList = (ExpendableListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
         //create and set adapter here.
         return root;

    }
```

Activity Class

private ViewPager mPager;
   private FragmentStatePagerAdapter mAdapter;

```
public void onCreate(... ) {

  super(..}
  setContentView(...) 
  mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
  mAdapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
  //In the Adapter create List of Fragments 
  ExpendListFragment fragment = new ExpendListFragment();
  mAdapter.add(fragment);
  mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

}

Hope it Helps.

Comment: I use ViewPage for swipe on the page... what I have to change on your example?

Comment: I've done all this to make the swipe tabs. My problem is that I don't know how to add a list on a specific fragment tab(i've done it on xml but I don't have an idea on what to implement on the fragment file because every example i find uses code for activities). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the Tabs and the Fragments are not related. the Tabs are related to the ViewPager. i showed in the code above how to create the list inside the fragment. in the expendableList you need Adapter same as the Activities